# cache_read stream error: cannot pre fill buffer

Tags: python, libvlc

I am trying to run my code on another PC and I got this error\warning;

> *[0000014d1968b210] cache_read stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
>
> [0000014d197ceb50] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek*

It is worth noting that I am running exactly the same code on my laptop without any error\warning.
A piece of my code is presented here;

```
import vlc  
import random
my_audio=vlc.MediaPlayer("audio.mp3")
for i in range(30):
    rand_list=[random.randint(1,30) for i in range(30)]
    for num in rand_list:
        if num<4:
            my_audio.stop()
            my_audio.play()
            print(num)
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that we may have multiple values smaller than 4 in rand_list and consequently the audio may needs to be repeated while the previous played audio is not ended yet. However, this problem does not lead to any error\warning on another laptop as I have already mentioned.

Comment: You should put a time.sleep() between for loops. that will help you.

Comment: It creates a delay and that's not what I am looking for. However, I am satisfied even if the audio get played just one time for each iteration of first for-loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
import vlc 
import random
my_audio = vlc.MediaPlayer("audio.mp3")
for _ in range(30):
    duration = random.randint(1, 30)
    my_audio.play()
    print("Playing for", duration, "seconds")
    vlc.libvlc_media_player_set_time(my_audio, duration * 1000)  # Set 
    playback time in milliseconds
    my_audio.pause()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).